# How to create *mut u8 from Rust string?

Tags: rust

I'm new to Rust. I want to create a mutable u8 buffer.

I tried

```
let mut str = "hello";
let r = str as *mut u8;
```

but I get

```
error[E0606]: casting `&str` as `*mut u8` is invalid
```

I want to know how but also why. What is the type of "hello"? How does casting works on Rust?

Comment: @Stargateur thanks. But if `u8` is a primite type, how can Vec create a buffer of them? This is what I'm missing and couldn't find on tutorials

Comment: It is actually a slice of u8 instead of u8. You can get one from Vec by taking a reference of a slice of the Vec.

Comment: Use the the `as_slice` method on the Vec or `&Vec[..]`

Comment: What do you want to use the `*mut u8` pointer for? It would help giving an answer.

Comment: It would help if you could give us more context. What are you trying to do, [what's your goal here?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) If you're new to Rust then it's unlikely that pointers will be the right answer, but we can't say what you should do instead without knowing more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: str doesn't need to be mutable because you are not mutating it.
Second: "hello" is of type `&str` (string slice).
Third: You can convert `&str` to `&[u8]` by calling as_bytes() on it, which is the buffer you needed. Appending `mut` before the variable name makes it mutable.

```rust
   let str = "hello";
   let mut r = str.as_bytes();
   println!("{:?}", r);
```

Comment: I guess "hello" is of type String and the method `as_bytes` returns a mutable u8 pointer? But what if I want to create my own mutable u8 pointer? How can I fill it?

Comment: my compiler says `r` has type `&[u8]`

Answer (score 0):

There is a method [`str::as_mut_ptr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.as_mut_ptr) that does exactly this.

```rust
let mut str = "hello";
let r = str.as_mut_ptr(); // r: *mut u8
```

However, you are responsible for upholding the safety invariants of `str` if you proceed to use `r`.  Quoting from the documentation (emphasis mine):

> Converts a mutable string slice to a raw pointer.
>
> As string slices are a slice of bytes, the raw pointer points to a `u8`.
> This pointer will be pointing to the first byte of the string slice.
>
> **It is your responsibility to make sure that the string slice only gets
> modified in a way that it remains valid UTF-8.**